# Vscode make 'go to definition' for all functions in workspace

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

a.js

```
function a() {
    console.log("hi")
}
```

b.js

```
a();
console.log("done")
```

In b.js, I would like to 'go to definition' to a.js.

In real project, there are a lot of scripts.

is it possible? and how can I do that unless opening all javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding an empty jsconfig.json file in the root of your directory will fix this.

just save a blank jsconfig.json with `{}` should work.